# Sort large set of array data with date and time using java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, datetime

Have a large list of array data of which can exceed to N number.
Need to sort the array elements with latest date and time.
[image]

```
let array = [{"name": "Apple","modified_date": "2020-08-26 02:03:23.756"},
             {"name": "Orange","modified_date": "2020-08-26 03:03:23.756"},
             {"name": "Grapes","modified_date": "2020-08-26 04:03:23.756"}................N number length]
```

able to sort using small size of array

```
let sort = array.sort(function(a, b) { 
            return (new Date(b.modified_date)).getTime() - (new Date(a.modified_date)).getTime();
        });
```

But with large length array correct sorting is not happening.What could be the issue!!!!?

Comment: What do you mean by "sorting is not happening"?

Comment: Plus 542 is not _that big_ to be honest, you might get a bit of a freeze when tackling 1m+ entries, in which case you could proceed within a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) (it won't reduce the sorting time, but will allow the UI not to freeze).

Comment: @Nick I mean correct sorting is not happening among the all N elements of array.

Comment: You mean that some of the results are not sorted in the correct order? Or that the sort doesn't finish?

Comment: @Nick Right. sort Finishes but not with correct sorted array.

Comment: @New123 Probably the specific input is needed..

Comment: I posted and answer, but it would have helped only if your sort function did not finish (as opposed to it not sorting correctly). There is no need to create `Date()` object. String compare should give you the same result here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could avoid creation of  `O(2*n*log(n))` `Date` objects. String compare will yield the same result as `Date(str).getTime()` compare yields. The string comparison method is a very much better idea.

```js
let array = [{"name": "Apple","modified_date": "2020-08-26 02:03:23.756"},
             {"name": "Orange","modified_date": "2020-08-26 03:03:23.756"},
             {"name": "Grapes","modified_date": "2020-08-26 04:03:23.756"}];

array.sort((a, b) => b.modified_date.localeCompare(a.modified_date));
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Actually the results will be different since in some browsers `new Date("2020-08-26 02:03:23.756").getTime()` returns NaN. The string comparison method is a very much better idea. ;-)